# How should I ensure disposal of possibly disposable objects?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, idisposable

I am working on a .NET project, which needs to interact with some user defined classes - reffered to as "jobs". All job classes must implement a specific interface `IJob` in order order for the library to consume them. Sometimes a job class might hold unmanaged resource, which needs to be explicitly disposed.

How should I ensure that all jobs are properly disposed after use, if I do not know in advance if the job needs explicit disposal? I have a few ideas myself, but would like to hear your comments/suggestions:

1. Make `IJob : IDisposable`, forcing all jobs to implement a `Dispose()` method. This will allow me to work with jobs in `using` blocks, but as most jobs are *not* expected to need explicit disposal, this might add unneeded confusion for the client developers.
2. Do all work involving jobs in `try-finally` blocks, and use `finally` to ensure that `Dispose()` is called if the job implements `IDisposable`. This makes it easier for clients to implement a new job class - by not having to implement an empty `Dispose()` method - but it also hides the fact that the library knows and cares about disposable jobs.

After writing this up, I tend to lean towards solution #1, but I still think it would be nice to see alternative solutions, and additional pros/cons to the two I already have in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a precedent: The Stream base class is IDisposable nad therefore all Streams descendants are. But MemoryStream doesn't need Disposing.
But don't aim for try/finally,  the `using() { }` block is a more convenient shorthand.

So your choice is: Do you want all Jobs to be IDisposable or just some?

The first option incurs a small overhead, the second one makes it easier to forget Dispose (using) when it is necessary.

Comment: Good point. However, most streams will need disposal, and I expect a only minority of jobs to need that.

Comment: It occurs to me that `System.Web.IHttpModule` also requires its implementors to provide a `Dispose()` method, even though only few modules (IMHO) needs it. I guess this provides additional precedence for #1.

Comment: +1, I think moreover, it makes sense to provide a standardized method for a Job to clean up what it used. By using `IDisposable` you get to benefit from the framework support and end-users benefit from at least having to think about where to place appropriate cleanup code.

Comment: +1 the second option also has a disadvantage that it's easy to "lose" IDisposable in an adapter. Having adapters and querying for interfaces does not mix well. Making things more explicit makes maintenance easier.

Answer (score 5):

#2 is how the `foreach` construct works. It is also how Autofac's container disposal works.

The semantic difference is whether you say that a job itself *is* disposable, or whether an implementation *might be* disposable.

It is clear from your example that the former is not true, that jobs are not inherently disposable. Therefore, I recommend #2, but with an extension method to centralize the `try/finally`:

```
public static void Execute(this IJob job)
{
    try
    {
        job.Run();
    }
    finally
    {
        var disposableJob = job as IDisposable;

        if(disposableJob != null)
        {
            disposableJob.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, I like your argument about semantics, but I think I will go with the first solution, for the reasons mentioned in the other answers and the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

I think of it this way. I'd rather a developer implement an empty `Dispose` method than forget to implement a necessary `Dispose` method.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with #2 and document that any disposable object will be disposed. Basically if you take ownership of an object you are obligated to dispose of objects that implement IDisposable.

If you read Effective C#/ More Effective C#, Bill Wagner give the same advice (which I agree with obviously ;-)

Comment: The OP is already disposing owned objects in both options, so I don't see how this is an argument for option #2.