# What is the right way to dispose an object of which I only have an interface?

Tags: c#, interface, idisposable

I have an interface that describes a certain business logic, i.e.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}
```

I also have got a few implementations of that interface, such as

```
public class ConcreteFoo1 : IFoo
{
    public void Bar() {...}
}

public class ConcreteFoo2 : IFoo, IDisposable
{
    public void Bar() {...}
    public void Dispose {...}
}
```

Within a client I now get an instance of IFoo via dependency injection - so I have no idea which one I am getting. But I need to make sure that Dispose is being called when I get an instance of ConcreteFoo2 and am done with it.

I think I have got 2 options, but please correct me if I have more, better ones.

1. **Have IFoo extending IDisposable**
   This is not great, as it requires all implementations of IFoo to also implement IDisposable. But it allows me to use the using {...} syntax.
2. **Require all clients to check for IDisposable and call it if necessary.**
   This would make it simpler on the implementations but shift the responsibility to the client, which have to do something like this

```cs
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        IFoo foo = ....;
        //do stuff

        IDisposable disposable = foo as IDisposable;
        if(disposable != null)
        { 
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Is there any other / better way of ensuring that Dispose() is getting called deterministically? Are there pro's and con's to either of the two approaches?

Comment: Generally the _creator_ of an object is responsible for disposing it.  So your function should not be disposing of the object at all.

Comment: There is no right way, disposing an object that you didn't create is a bug.

Comment: I would either make `IFoo` implement `IDisposable` and people who don't need it simply implement it empty.

The other approach is an abstract base class, which is still a *contract* just not an `interface`. This base class could then provide an empty implementation of `IDisposable` to save the derived classes from having to do it. It could then also let you disconnect `IFoo` from `IDisposable` by having just the base class implement both interfaces, if `IFoo` semantically doesn't need `IDisposable`. All that said, if you are *given* an `IFoo` you shouldn't be disposing it, as others say.

Comment: If you only know you're getting an `IFoo`, how do you know it's an `IDisposable`?  If you _know_ it is, then `IFoo` should implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975825/how-should-i-ensure-disposal-of-possibly-disposable-objects?rq=1

Comment: @DavidCrowell I am controlling both sides, so I know that I might get one. Which one I get however is determined by some other logic. So all I know is that I _might_ get one.

Comment: @StephanHoffmann Then you should look to dispose it from the side that supplies the disposable type, not the side that simply needs to make use of it. Look to see if your DI container will do disposal for you (assuming you are using one).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Yes, we (currently) use Unity to inject the concrete instance. We do need a new instance with each call.

Comment: Adding `IDisposable` to something that's supposed to be an abstraction often yields a *leaky abstraction*. A good DI container can help with resolving this issue; [here's an Autofac article about solving it](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/).

Comment: @HansPassant It's not a bug, it's a red flag that should make you think long and hard about whether or not your program is correctly designed.  A great counter-example is `IEnumerator`.  The objects creating it are never responsible for disposing of it, and they are exposed via the interface, not an underlying implementation.  However it is an unusual situation, so seeing it a  lot is a strong indication that there is a better design.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: The responsibility for `Dispose` should lie with whoever is going to know when the object isn't needed anymore.  If the supplier will know, then the supplier can be responsible for the object.  In many cases, however, such as with `IEnumerator<T>`, the recipient must be responsible for calling `Dispose` because *nobody else will have any way of knowing when the recipient is done with the object*.

Comment: @supercat Yes I agree, my comment was poorly worded.